# Not able to apply function to Spark Dataframe Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, udf

I am trying to apply a function to one of my dataframe columns to convert the values. The values in the column are like "20160907" I need value to be "2016-09-07".

I wrote a function like this:

```
def convertDate(inDate:String ): String = {
   val year = inDate.substring(0,4)
   val month = inDate.substring(4,6)
   val day = inDate.substring(6,8)

   return year+'-'+month+'-'+day
}
```

And in my spark scala code, I am using this:

```
def final_Val {
  val oneDF = hiveContext.read.orc("/tmp/new_file.txt")
  val convertToDate_udf = udf(convertToDate _)
  val convertedDf = oneDF.withColumn("modifiedDate", convertToDate_udf(col("EXP_DATE")))
  convertedDf.show()
}
```

Suprisingly, in spark shell I am able to run without any error. In scala IDE I am getting the below compilation error:

```
Multiple markers at this line:
not enough arguments for method udf: (implicit evidence$2: 
reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String], implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String])org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction. Unspecified value parameters evidence$2, evidence$3.
```

I am using Spark 1.6.2, Scala 2.10.5

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Same code I tried with different functions like in this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/35227568/applying-function-to-spark-dataframe-column".
I am not getting any compilation issues with this code. I am unable to find out the issue with my code

Comment: Here is a similar answer you can change the dateformat as you want
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018393/change-column-value-in-a-dataframe-spark-scala/44020820#44020820](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018393/change-column-value-in-a-dataframe-spark-scala/44020820#44020820)

Comment: Why udf(convertToDate _) and not just udf(convertToDate)?

Comment: @RobertHorvick Because udf needs a function as input, not a method. ith the underscore you "lift" the method to a function

Comment: Works fine for me in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Not working in eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have learned in a spark-summit course, you have to use the `sql.functions` methods as much as possible. before implementing your own `udf` you have to check if there's no existing `function` in the [`sql.functions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions) package that does the same work. using the existing functions *spark* can do a lot of **optimizations** for you and it will not be obliged to serialize and deserialize you data from and to JVM objects.

to achieve the result you want I'm gonna propose this solution :

```
val oneDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("19931001", "19931001")).toDF("EXP_DATE")
val convertedDF = oneDF.withColumn("modifiedDate", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"EXP_DATE", "yyyyMMdd"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
convertedDF.show()
```

this gives the following results :

```
+--------+------------+
|EXP_DATE|modifiedDate|
+--------+------------+
|19931001|  1993-10-01|
|19931001|  1993-10-01|
+--------+------------+
```

Hope this help. Best Regards

Comment: @user3497321 please make the answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, this is giving a compilation error: **too many arguments (3) for method withColumn: (colName: String, col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame**

Comment: there was parenthesis miss order I've just edited the answer

Comment: there was also a problem with `.cast("timestamp")`. the code should works now. with me at least

Comment: Perfect. Thank you